# Looking for the Category of Quantum Systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, category-theory

I've recently written a comment in a different forum to a question about how to implement infinite potentials in quantum mechanics, that is things like a non-relativistic particle in an infinite potential well, in a rigorous way. Mathematically rigorous sources usually treat these systems by manually limiting the domain of definition of the wave functions and examining boundary conditions which make certain observables ess. self adjoint. My take on this is that these systems should in some sense be seen as "limits" of quantum systems with finite potentials. I'm not familiar with mathematically rigorous treatments of potentials, which have apparently fourished since the 50s; I've been told by many physicists that their results aren't really interesting from a physical point of view. My question is: How would one view a quantum system as a limiting case of other quantum systems. I believe this is a meaningfull concept.

I would like to phrase this concept in a category-theoretic language. The idea is for the limiting system to be a categorical limit (inductive limit) of the other systems. My first attempt by just guessing failed miserably and I'm not sure how to continue, nor have I been able to find any sources for this.

My guess was this: A Quantum System in my view should be a pair $(\mathcal{H},H)$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is a complex Hilbert space and $H:\mathcal{D}_H\to \mathcal H$ a self-adjoint, possibly unbounded linear operator (Hamiltonian. I'm not considering explicit time dependance) These are to be the objects in a category. My first guess at what a morphism should look like was this:
A morphism from $(\mathcal{H},H)$ to $(\mathcal{K},K)$ is a bounded linear map $\psi:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{K}$ such that $\psi(\mathcal{D}_H)\subseteq \mathcal{D}_K$ and for all $v\in\mathcal{D}_H$: $\psi(Hv)=K\psi(v)$.

This would lead to a notion of equivalence of quantum systems (isomorphism) that seems appropriate to me (I guess it's almost too obvious that this was my starting point). However there do not exist any morphisms between the quantum systems of non-relativistic particles that have different constant potentials on bounded subset of space. This leads me to conclude that the above is useless nonsense.

> What is the correct framework for the Category of Quantum Systems? Are there sources on this? Has this concept been usefull or are there immediate reasons to believe it could be?

My general aim is to find a precise sense in which a quantum system can be a limiting case or a subsystem of other systems. If this can be done in a satisfactory manner, I think showing that certain cases of Koopman-von Neumann Classical Mechanics are a limit of quantum systems gives a nice perspective on "the classical limit".

Comment: The description of the limit you're searching for has nothing to do with category theory, but instead is simply the $\hbar\to 0$ limit of the phase space description of quantum mechanics. There exist categorial formulations of quantum mechanics (just search for "categorial quantum mechanics") but they have not really much to do with the classical limit.